# glShaderSource, 0:1(1): error: syntax error, unexpected $end

Tags: c++, pointers, opengl, memory-leaks, shader

I've seen tons of similiar questions, but no matter what I try, I can't get OpenGL to load my shader source. My first thought was, the pointer data might
go out of scope, which was right. So i saved the string in a variable, but OpenGL still gives me an Error.

```
/**
 * Load shaders
 */
void GraphicsCore::loadShaders() {
  // Create the main program
  GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();

  // Vertex shader
  GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  std::string vsSource = Utilities::fileToString("main.vert");
  const GLchar* v = vsSource.c_str();
  glShaderSource(vs,1,&v,nullptr);
  std::cout << v;
  glCompileShader(vs);
  glAttachShader(prog,vs);

  // Fragment shader
  GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  std::string fsSource = Utilities::fileToString("main.frag");
  const GLchar* f = fsSource.c_str();
  glShaderSource(fs,1,&f,nullptr);
  std::cout << f;
  glCompileShader(fs);
  glAttachShader(prog,fs);

  // Link program and use
  glLinkProgram(prog);
  glUseProgram(prog);
}
```

Utilities::fileToString("main.vert") returns a normal string, no pointers, no references. The cout calls both print the shader source as it should be,
but when I'm running the application in BuGLe, the debugger already breaks on
Vertex Shader compilation with the following message:

```
0:1(1): error: syntax error, unexpected $end
```

It seems that OpenGL doesn't find the data at all, but just in case, the vertex shader code:

```
#version 120
void main() { gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix * gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex; }
```

**UPDATE**

Things just got even stranger. I tried to write the shade inline and made sure to have the exact same code in the file and as inline code. The surprising thing is, the inline code works:

```
std::string vsSource = "#version 120\nvoid main() { gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix * gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex; }";
std::string vsSource2 = Utilities::fileToString("main.vert");
```

In the above code, vsSource is compiled without any errors, whereas vsSource2 gives the initial error, as mentioned above. Even if I copy the string with vsSource = vsSource2, OpenGL still won't compile the Shader. I checked the shader content in GDB; The string from the file, as well as the inline string have an equal content, byte for byte. The following code is the method used to load the shader:

```
std::string Utilities::fileToString(const char* filename) {
  std::ifstream f(filename,std::ios::binary);
  if(f) {
    std::string contents;
    f.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
    contents.resize(f.tellg());
    f.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
    f.read(&contents[0], contents.size());
    f.close();
    return contents;
  }
  return "";
}
```

**UPDATE String memory dump**

Both strings are are 96 Characters long (without \0)

```
(gdb) x/96c &vsSource[0]
0x2169ae8:      35 '#'  118 'v' 101 'e' 114 'r' 115 's' 105 'i' 111 'o' 110 'n'
0x2169af0:      32 ' '  49 '1'  50 '2'  48 '0'  10 '\n' 118 'v' 111 'o' 105 'i'
0x2169af8:      100 'd' 32 ' '  109 'm' 97 'a'  105 'i' 110 'n' 40 '('  41 ')'
0x2169b00:      32 ' '  123 '{' 32 ' '  103 'g' 108 'l' 95 '_'  80 'P'  111 'o'
0x2169b08:      115 's' 105 'i' 116 't' 105 'i' 111 'o' 110 'n' 32 ' '  61 '='
0x2169b10:      32 ' '  103 'g' 108 'l' 95 '_'  80 'P'  114 'r' 111 'o' 106 'j'
0x2169b18:      101 'e' 99 'c'  116 't' 105 'i' 111 'o' 110 'n' 77 'M'  97 'a'
0x2169b20:      116 't' 114 'r' 105 'i' 120 'x' 32 ' '  42 '*'  32 ' '  103 'g'
0x2169b28:      108 'l' 95 '_'  77 'M'  111 'o' 100 'd' 101 'e' 108 'l' 86 'V'
0x2169b30:      105 'i' 101 'e' 119 'w' 77 'M'  97 'a'  116 't' 114 'r' 105 'i'
0x2169b38:      120 'x' 32 ' '  42 '*'  32 ' '  103 'g' 108 'l' 95 '_'  86 'V'
0x2169b40:      101 'e' 114 'r' 116 't' 101 'e' 120 'x' 59 ';'  32 ' '  125 '}'
(gdb) x/96c &vsSource2[0]
0xbc4d28:       35 '#'  118 'v' 101 'e' 114 'r' 115 's' 105 'i' 111 'o' 110 'n'
0xbc4d30:       32 ' '  49 '1'  50 '2'  48 '0'  10 '\n' 118 'v' 111 'o' 105 'i'
0xbc4d38:       100 'd' 32 ' '  109 'm' 97 'a'  105 'i' 110 'n' 40 '('  41 ')'
0xbc4d40:       32 ' '  123 '{' 32 ' '  103 'g' 108 'l' 95 '_'  80 'P'  111 'o'
0xbc4d48:       115 's' 105 'i' 116 't' 105 'i' 111 'o' 110 'n' 32 ' '  61 '='
0xbc4d50:       32 ' '  103 'g' 108 'l' 95 '_'  80 'P'  114 'r' 111 'o' 106 'j'
0xbc4d58:       101 'e' 99 'c'  116 't' 105 'i' 111 'o' 110 'n' 77 'M'  97 'a'
0xbc4d60:       116 't' 114 'r' 105 'i' 120 'x' 32 ' '  42 '*'  32 ' '  103 'g'
0xbc4d68:       108 'l' 95 '_'  77 'M'  111 'o' 100 'd' 101 'e' 108 'l' 86 'V'
0xbc4d70:       105 'i' 101 'e' 119 'w' 77 'M'  97 'a'  116 't' 114 'r' 105 'i'
0xbc4d78:       120 'x' 32 ' '  42 '*'  32 ' '  103 'g' 108 'l' 95 '_'  86 'V'
0xbc4d80:       101 'e' 114 'r' 116 't' 101 'e' 120 'x' 59 ';'  32 ' '  125 '}'
```

The source code from, right before being passed to glShaderSource:

```
(gdb) print v
$1 = (const GLchar *) 0xbc4d28 "#version 120\nvoid main() { gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix * gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex; }"
(gdb) x/96c 0xbc4d28
0xbc4d28:       35 '#'  118 'v' 101 'e' 114 'r' 115 's' 105 'i' 111 'o' 110 'n'
0xbc4d30:       32 ' '  49 '1'  50 '2'  48 '0'  10 '\n' 118 'v' 111 'o' 105 'i'
0xbc4d38:       100 'd' 32 ' '  109 'm' 97 'a'  105 'i' 110 'n' 40 '('  41 ')'
...
```

Comment: `((const GLchar**)&v)[0]` What is the point of this?

Comment: No point, just copy & paste for debug output.

Comment: `&v` is already `const GLchar**`. I don't understand the cast.

Comment: Yea, the casts were redundant, they are gone now.

Comment: `std::ios::in` You don't need to provide this to istreams. It's implicit.

Comment: The way you read the string from the file, I don't think it will be zero terminated. Try allocating it one byte bigger, and write a `\0` at the end. Or use functions like `getline()` that operate with C++ string.

Comment: Magic is too unlikely to happen. Since GL have no idea where you data comes from (nor it cares), either 'equal content, byte for byte' statement is wrong, or there is a hidden stack/heap corruption. `valgrind` can help you check for heap corruption. But it is more like data is just not equal; check `strlen` and/or dump hex values for each byte. As for `\0` - looks ok, `c_str` returns correct terminated C string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ran `valgrind` and it gave me `Syscall param writev(vector[...]) points to uninitialised byte(s)` somewhere in X11, but nothing other than that. I added memory examinations to the question, plus a check of the string right before it gets passed to glShaderSource.

Comment: Does C++11 guarantee that `nullptr` is equivalent to `NULL`? I'm not hip to modern C++. That is my biggest concern right now, if `nullptr` != `NULL`, then GL could be dereferencing an array of memory somewhere to figure out the length, which it appears to think is **0**. I would really avoid introducing C++ (especially C++11) constructs to an API that was built using C. If the API says it expects something to use `NULL`, then do that ;)

Comment: In your hex dumps, if you show one byte more, we can see if both strings are indeed equally zero terminated.

Comment: null-termination really is not the problem here. The shader compiler is complaining that the first character of the first line is the end of the shader, which means it thinks the shader has zero length. The only way that's going to happen is if it thinks it was passed an array of lengths - which leads me back to my previous comment. I did some tests and `nullptr` == `NULL` generates an assertion failure, so whatever `nullptr` is, it's not appropriate.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman what OS/compiler it is? As far as I'm aware `nullptr` is required to match `(void*)0`, so it is the same as 0 or NULL cast to pointer type (which is technically not required to match all-zero-bits, but I've never seen a system where it isn't).

Comment: @user3413372 can you make minimal compilable example? Sounds too weird. If minimal example would work fine - then problem isn't in given code.

Comment: @keltar: MSVC targeting either Win32 or x64. But I dug a little deeper and the test case I was using was treating comparison against `NULL` as an `int` expression, while comparison against `nullptr` was `void*`. That little tidbit only matters if you have a class with different operators for those two types. Straight up constant expressions probably are not going to be an issue, `nullptr` is already `std::nullptr_t` which requires no conversion to get to `void *`.